# How to Check Authentication Status in Outlook for Mac (2016)

Tags: macos, email, ms-office, exchange, authentication

At the University where I work, we've recently made the switch to Modern Authentication.  This has caused a lot of issues for users, with previously configured mail clients not properly negotiating connections with the mail servers.  In Windows Outlook, I've been able to check if a client is properly authenticated by checking the "Authn" authentication column in Outlook's "Connection Status" window (See Microsoft's documentation [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/connectivity/description-of-the-connection-status-dialog-box)).  If the authentication is broken, I can tell it's getting stuck negotiating the connection, because it displays a "NEGO" status in the "Authn" column.  However, if the mail client is functioning properly, I can see a "BEARER" displayed in the "Authn" column.

I'm wondering if the Mac version, Outlook for Mac (2016), has any sort of feature parity for the "Connection Status" window.  I've checked Microsoft's [Support Tools](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/outlook-for-mac/useful-tools), but none of them seem to be relevant.  I've also checked for anything in `/Applications/Microsoft Outlook.app/Contents/SharedSupport/`, but nothing seemed relevant there either, as the Microsoft Activity Monitor fails to launch.

To reprise/**TLDR**: I'm wondering if there's a way to check if a client is stuck negotiating authentication on Outlook for Mac (2016).

**Bonus**: I would love to be able to push a command out through Apple Remote Desktop to find clients that aren't authenticating properly, so a Terminal/bash/zsh solution would be fantastic.  I haven't been able to find anything about builtin command line tools for Outlook though...

**Edit**: I've been looking at the logs in `~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Outlook/Data/Library/Logs/Diagnostic/` and there may be some relevant information in there, but the "Logging for Troubleshooting" may need to be enabled in Outlook.

Comment: We shut off access at noon to clients and it was painful. Good on you for trying to validate this on each endpoint before the transition. I’ll answer if I can find anything appropriate to mitigate risk. We’re ripping out 2016 as fast as we can since it’s no longer supported - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/release-notes-office-2016-mac

Comment: We're moving to O365 from an on-site exchange server, and the Windows clients were fine but I had to remove and re-add the account on iOS and macOS to get the clients to switch over. And this is AFTER the macOS client popped up a message about letting it authenticate from the new server. I am afraid that the macOS versions of MS Office are *still* 2nd class citizens...